# Is it possible to pass parameters into a function using a switch statement in c++?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, switch-statement

Is there any way to pass parameters into functions using switch statements in c++?  What I am trying to achieve is turning a series of if statements into one switch statement.

As an example, I'd like to turn this:

```
if (function(a)) {
  //code
}

if (function(b)) {
  //code
}

if (function(c)) {
  //code
}
```

into this:

```
switch (function(a/b/c)) {
case a:
  //code
case b:
  //code
case c:
  //code
}
```

The function returns true or false depending on whether or not a, b, or c is active.  It is important to note that a, b, and c would indeed be constants, but the function itself would determine whether or not they're currently active.  The problem I am working on is whether or not a key is currently pressed when the function is given the key code to check.  It looks something like this:

```
if (isKeyPressed(Key::A)) {
  //code
}
```

Is this possible or does it break what a switch statement fundamentally is?

Comment: It would really help to know what `function()` actually does, what `a`/`b`/`c` are, and what your actual goal is.  A series of `if`s that each call the function with different inputs is fundamentally different than a `switch` calling the function 1 time.

Comment: Can `function` return a true value for more than one of the inputs? If it does, should every matching block be executed, or only the first one?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the function can return true for more than one of the inputs and all cases that results in true should be ran.

Comment: In that case, you probably aren't going to improve over the original code. You could use a for loop to run the function repeatedly, but you want to do something different with each result, so.

Comment: Actually, I suppose you could build a structure that maps the `Key::A` etc. symbols to functions, and iterate over that structure to check if the key was pressed and then call the corresponding function. C++ certainly doesn't make this as easy as some other languages, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how a `switch` is used.  It would need to look more like this instead:

```cpp
switch (someValue)
{
case value1:
  function(a);
  break;
case value2:
  function(b);
  break;
case value3:
  function(c);
  break;
}
```

If that is not what you are looking for, then the [`?:` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) *may* work for you, depending on what your inputs actually are, eg:

```cpp
function( condition1 ? a : (condition2 ? b : c) );
```

Or, maybe you are trying to calling the function 1 time and get different kinds of output depending on the input, that you can then test for?  If so, then `std::variant` *may* be what you are looking for, eg:

```cpp
std::variant<a,b,c> function()
{
  return ...;
}

auto v = function(input);
if (std::holds_alternative<a>(v)) {
  //code
}

else if (std::holds_alternative<b>(v)) {
  //code
}

else if (std::holds_alternative<c>(v)) {
  //code
}
```

Or:

```cpp
auto v = function(input);
switch (v.index()) {
  case 0: // a
    //code
    break;
  case 1: // b
    //code
    break;
  case 2: // c
    //code
    break;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
auto v = function(input);
std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
  using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, a>) {
    // code
  }
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, b>) {
    // code
  }
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, c>) {
    // code
  }
}, v);
```

Or:

```cpp
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

auto v = function(input);
std::visit(overloaded {
  [](a arg) { /* code */ },
  [](b arg) { /* code */ },
  [](c arg) { /* code */ },
}, v);
```